# Missing HID_Utilities.h on Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, input

I'm trying to build with IO for Mac, but I don't seem to have the file  with friends installed. When I googled for it, it seemed to me like it was part of, or related to, glut implementation on Mac? Glut is installed. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's anything to do with GLUT - it's for USB input devices. Anyway, try here: http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/samplecode/HID_Utilities_Source/Introduction/Intro.html - this seems to be the latest version of the sample code which includes HID_Utilities.h *et al*.